# Getting IPv6 IP on Windows 10

Tags: ipv6

I'm trying to find a easy way to add a IPv6 IP to my home Windows 10 machine for testing. I did find the following project

http://www.freenet6.net/download.shtml

which can give me a IPv6 IP by downloading their client. But there is nothing to download on their download page. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

The gogo6/Freenet6 project was shut down in April 2016. The website you found is fake and just has a random mix of information about three different projects named "Freenet". (It has logos for a TV channel and a P2P filesharing network.)

(SiXXS has also shut down in July 2017.)

As of October 2017, if your ISP does not offer native IPv6, your options are:

- Hurricane Electric's [Tunnelbroker](https://tunnelbroker.net/).
- NetAssist's [tunnel broker service](http://tb.netassist.ua/).
- Private tunnel through a remote server. Many VPS providers technically support IPv6, although most of them do so poorly (providing only an "on-link" prefix and requiring ndppd). One which provides a "routed" prefix would be best.
- 6to4, if you can configure it on your router. It provides a /48 address block for every single IPv4 address, automatically setting up a tunnel through a nearby relay. (The numbers are dwindling and 6to4 as a whole is on its way out, but it works in a pinch.)
- Teredo, if all you need is *one* address. Windows comes with native Teredo support but Microsoft no longer runs the relays; you would need to configure a third-party server.

Comment: If I create a OpenVPN server on a VPS with IPv6, can I gain IPv6 IP when I connect to the VPN using my IPv4?

Comment: Yes, if your provider offers a range of addresses, you can configure part of it in OpenVPN. (Though as noted above many VPS hosts only provide an "on-link" /64, not a routed one – so that would require you to additionally run `ndppd` to let OpenVPN use part of it.)